# How can I declare this function to return a TFuture? UE5 C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I have been trying to declare this function in my header file (using ue5 c++) and I get the compiler telling me this error:

> Unrecognized type 'TFuture' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT, UENUM, or global delegate. [UnrealHeaderTool ParserError]*

```
static TFuture<UTexture2D*> ImportImageFromDiskAsync(UObject* Outer, const FString& ImagePath, TFunction<void()> CompletionCallback);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "PixelFormat.h"
#include "UObject/NoExportTypes.h"
#include "Async/Future.h"
#include "TSImageLoader.generated.h"

// Forward Declare Texture 2D
class UTexture2D;

DECLARE_LOG_CATEGORY_EXTERN(LogTextureSerializeImageLoading, Log, All);

UCLASS(BlueprintType)
class TEXTURESERIALIZEIO_API UTSImageLoader : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, meta  = (HidePin = "Outer", DefaultToSelf = "Outer"))
static TFuture<UTexture2D*> ImportImageFromDiskAsync(UObject* Outer, const FString& ImagePath, TFunction<void()> CompletionCallback);

};
```

Comment: Do you have `#include "Async/Future.h"` in your header? Hard to diagnose your problem without seeing a [mcve] of your actual code.

Comment: Ah I'll edit it now with that. First time asking a question here :) I have it included yeah

Comment: I do not have UE5 on my system but I guess you need to declare the texture like this: `UClass UTexture2D;` You might also neef to include `"UObject/Class.h"`

Comment: @AshutoshRaghuwanshi None of that is true.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work... From what I've found in the unreal docs TFuture is supposed to go TFuture<TemplateGoesHere>

It is vexing atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

TFuture cannot be returned on a function that would be exposed to blueprints. So removing the UFUNCTION() tag above it solves the issue.

Comment: This is why posting a [mcve] is important. What you posted was minimal, but you didn’t check that it reproduced the problem.

Comment: Yep. Lesson Learned. Thanks